# Problem with Xcode organizer screen capture

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, screenshot, ipod-touch

I'm currently running Xcode 3.2.2 on Snow Leopard. When opening Organizer > Screenshots I see a list of screenshots I did before. But when I click the Capture button, nothing's happening. I don't see any messages popping up or any errors from the Console tab. I also tried restoring the iPod Touch (2nd gen) but that didn't help. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Xcode an not your iPod touch.  I would think that updating the iPod touch's firmware (to iOS 4) and then update Xcode and the iPhone SDK (3.2.3) to the newest version should resolve the issue.  It may be a compatibility gig between your iPod and Xcode.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update this question. But yes, the upgrade to iOS4 and latest Xcode version I did several days ago helped. Thanks!